# Trying to read some bytes from a big text file java

Tags: java, text, binary, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I need to read several bytes (say 1 MB, 2 MB...) from a 700MB file.

I tried several approaches but in everyone of them I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried using JDK 8 streams:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("myfilename"),
                                        Charset.defaultCharset())) {
    lines.forEachOrdered(line -> doSomething(line));
}
```

and also using `InputStream` / `OutputStream`:

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("myfilename");
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    is.close();
    return result.toString("UTF-8");
```

Is there anything I am missing?
Thanks!

Yes, it is binary file. So this is the problem... how can I read a portion of it?

Comment: That is kinda weird. And you are sure that there is no other code sitting around that you are not showing to us trying to open the whole file at once? Worst case: try using a profiler to understand where your memory is going to ...

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Here you get an OOME because you obviously load the entire file into memory which doesn't fit in the memory allocated to your JVM

Comment: Are you by any chance reading a binary file? The lazily streamed `Files.lines ()` can be used only with text files, since the end of a line is determined by the platform-specific line separator. If you try to load a binary file this way, it might read all bytes up to the first end-of-line sequence, if it's present at all (provided a charset conversion error doesn't occur). Thus it might throw OoME on the very first line.

Comment: Your second example is not working because you save the file to ByteArrayOutputStream and you don't have enough memory for that. If you use file output stream your 2nd example will most definitely work

Comment: I edited the question. Yes is a binary file

Answer (score 0):

Using JVM in 32-bit mode, the maximum heap size that can be allocated is 1280 MB. So, if you want to go beyond that, you need to invoke JVM in 64-mode.

Try to use options for java execution:

xms = min memory allocated

xmx = max memory allocated

```
JVM_ARGS="-d64 -Xms1024m -Xmx15360m "
jdk1.X/bin/java $JVM_ARGS -jar myprogram.jar
```